# Confusion about two forms of connection coefficients

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I am new to GR. In one book I found that the [connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection) coefficient expression is given by
$$ \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda} = -\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu\rho} (\partial_\nu g_{\lambda\rho} + \partial_\lambda g_{\rho\nu} - \partial_\rho g_{\nu\lambda}). $$
In another book I found
$$ g_{\rho\mu} \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda} = -\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\nu g_{\lambda\rho} + \partial_\lambda g_{\rho\nu} - \partial_\rho g_{\nu\lambda}). $$
Is one of them wrong; if not, how can I go from one to the other? Multiplying both sides by $g_{\rho\mu}$ seems to give the trace, which is 4 rather than 1.

Comment: Hi Sayan Datta, and welcome to Physics Stackexchange! Note that we support [LaTeX-style MathJax](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for math formatting. You can click "edit" to see how I formatted your equations if you're not familiar with the syntax.

Comment: $\uparrow$ The sign convention (v3) is non-standard. Which books?

Comment: One must have been Hartle, the other was Lectures on Gravitation by Das. I may be wrong, because I had the three GR books that I own by my side and a few sites (one was googlebooks) opened on the laptop. I can't quite exactly remember which equation came from which.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\rho$ is already a summed-over dummy index in the first equation, we can't introduce it again. Instead, multiply both sides of the first equation by $g_{\sigma\mu}$:
\begin{align}
g_{\sigma\mu} \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda} & = -\frac{1}{2} g_{\sigma\mu} g^{\mu\rho} (\partial_\nu g_{\lambda\rho} + \partial_\lambda g_{\rho\nu} - \partial_\rho g_{\nu\lambda}) \\
& = -\frac{1}{2} \delta_\sigma^\rho (\partial_\nu g_{\lambda\rho} + \partial_\lambda g_{\rho\nu} - \partial_\rho g_{\nu\lambda}) \\
& = -\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\nu g_{\lambda\sigma} + \partial_\lambda g_{\sigma\nu} - \partial_\sigma g_{\nu\lambda}).
\end{align}
This is your second equation, with $\sigma$ replacing $\rho$ as one of the free indices.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the prompt answer. I follow your steps completely, but just one more related question - If after your last step, I change the name of the free index from $\sigma$ to $\rho$ and rewrite the equation, would that be a legal step?

Comment: Yes, you can always replace all occurrences of an index with another one that is not already in use.

Comment: And if there is a second term (the first term can be the connection coefficients expanded in terms of the metric and its derivatives) **added** to the first in an equation, that (the second term) has a variable summed over, can I replace the name of that variable by something that already appears in the other part of the equation? Would that be illegal too?

Comment: While you *could* use the same dummy index in multiple locations (e.g. $g_{\alpha\beta} g^{\beta\gamma} + \Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma X^\beta$), this is a bit risky, and might lead to mistakes later on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps. To summarize, if I change the name of the free variables, I will have to do that in the entire equation, in whichever terms the indices appear. But in a particular term of an equation, I can always change the name of the dummy index to whatever I want. Although that might be risky, it is not strictly illegal. For example, I can change \alpha and \gamma in your equation to \rho and \sigma  , but I will have to do that in both terms. But if I wanted to change \beta to \nu only in the first term, I could always do that.

Comment: A final related query - if I were to change the name of some index, free or repeated, to something that is usually used for a parameter that parameterizes a trajectory, say like writing \lambda or \tau in place of \beta in your equation, that would be illegal, right?